# Using a git repo to manage your LDAP configuration

Tags: git, ldap

Is there a way that LDAP configurations can be synced from a file system, using an RPC call? I'd like to modify our current configuration management system (which unfortunately relies on LDAP for everything), to a git based configuration management where all key's/values in LDAP are updated only via git updates. (currently the updates can't be tracked, and there is no review system before a config change goes through.

Comment: It is possible to do via a normal deployment or CI/CD process; my employer does it.  I'm not aware of any automated tooling for it, so you'll have to either find some or write some yourself.